# Possible to compare two images in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

Is there a way to compare two image files that have different filenames?  So I am looking to see if they are equal with javascript.  Is this possible?

The use for this:
I have a gallery of images that needs to pop up in the lightbox.  When the lightbox opens, I am hooking into the callback to check for the duplicate images and when found, remove them from the lightbox gallery so users are not seeing repeated images.

Comment: Considering JavaScript does not access to the file system, no.

Comment: What kind of comparison are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to see if two images are identical even if they have different filenames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could. Psuedocode:

> - Check if the images have the same width and height. If not, they can't be the same.
> - Create a canvas that will fit both images side-by-side.
> - Draw the images on the canvas.
> - Compare them pixel-for-pixel. This can be done fairly easily using code borrowed from  [getPixel from HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)
> - Remember to break out of loops as soon as a single pixel doesn't match.
> - Your worst-case runtime will be O(wh), which occurs when the images are actually equal.

Comment: Yep, just what I was in the process of typing. It'd work, but'd be very, very slow for a large number of images.

Comment: Hmmm, in hindsight I think the better approach for me is to use AJAX and PHP to process the comparison....Seems using JS is quite complicated.

Comment: Eh, PHP would have to do a pixel-by-pixel comparison too. You'd just be putting load on your server instead of distributing it to the user's machine.

Comment: Sorry, i realized I did a horrible job explaining what I needed...I edited the post, so you can more clearly see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check images sizes if their sizes equal or not.

And do not forget to check widths and heights also.

[To find image file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: Two images can be visually identical while having different filesizes. Compare a full-RGB PNG image vs. the same image in Indexed-PNG. Compare that Indexed-PNG image vs. one with unused colours in the pallette.

Comment: Please give me an example, I'm courious about that.

Comment: http://adamhaskell.net/img/imgsize/ The same image three times, different saving methods, different filesizes, same format.

Comment: ok, thanks for this info. @Rick do not need that kind of sensivity, so he can use my method.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler is correct, you can't access the filesystem without the users' consent.

But if you want to compare images that are available to the javascript code, for example by using an url or using an upload field, you should check out this SO question: [Compare two Images in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066111/compare-two-images-in-javascript)

Basically, you convert the image to a `canvas` element and use the `base64` value to compare the two, the same way people confirm if a document is "valid" by checking the checksum of that document.