# How to match two images in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, cordova

I want to match two images with each other and if they matches then the result will be `true`. If it isn't then it will return `false`. But I want it in JavaScript.

Comment: what do you want to match? the name? the content?

Answer (score 1):

You can check by converting image into base64 string

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
// Create an empty canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

// Copy the image contents to the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// Get the data-URL formatted image
// Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
// guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
// will re-encode the image.
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Then

```
var a = new Image(),
    b = new Image();
a.src = url_a;
b.src = url_b;

var a_base64 = getBase64Image(a),
    b_base64 = getBase64Image(b);

if (a_base64 === b_base64)
{
    // they are identical
}
else
{
    // you can probably guess what this means
}
```

You can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066111/compare-two-images-in-javascript) to know more.

Comment: Those links are already given as reference. @NoDownvotesPlz

Comment: there is nothing wrong in combining two answers, but you should add some more stuff from yourself

Comment: Also you code doesnt work.. http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/hgs41ctd/