# Compare two images and see the difference using pixelmatch - refreshing canvas fails

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

In **[my codepen](https://codepen.io/surfmuggle-the-styleful/pen/WBOaeO)** i want to use [pixelmatch](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch) to show the difference of two images in the browser. The function is used like this

```
// img1, img2 — ImageData.data of the images to compare  
// output — ImageData to write the diff to, or null if don't need a diff image.
// width, height of the images - all 3 images need to have the same dimensions.


// calling pixelmatch  looks like this
var numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(img1.data, img2.data
      , imageDataOutput, wdth, hght, {threshold: 0.1});
```

### I got this to work

1. create an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)-Object from an `<img>`-tag and retrieve the data  as `Uint8Array` from the image
2. pass the `Uint8Array` for each image using  `imageData.data` to the function `pixelmatch`
3. fill `imageDataOutput` and get a number of different pixels in `numDiffixels`

**the HTML**

```
<p>
    <img id="imgBefore" src="./img/T1_Before.jpg">
    <img id="imgAfter" src="./img/T1_After.jpg"  >
</p>
<p>
    <button id="diff" class="js-compareImages">compare images</button>
    <canvas id="cnvDiff"></canvas>
</p>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

**Helper Function**

First a helper function to get a 'canvas' from an image

```
// Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
function convertImageToCanvas(imageID) {
    var image = document.getElementById(imageID);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    // image.style = "width: 400px";
    return canvas;
}
```

**The main function**

The the main function to compare the images

```
function compareImages()
{        
    var cnvBefore = convertImageToCanvas("imgBefore");
    var cnvAfter = convertImageToCanvas("imgAfter");

    var ctxBefore = cnvBefore.getContext("2d");
    var ctxAfter = cnvAfter.getContext("2d");

    let imgDataBefore = ctxBefore.getImageData(0,0,cnvBefore.width, cnvBefore.height);
    let imgDataAfter = ctxAfter.getImageData(0,0, cnvAfter.width, cnvAfter.height);   

    const hght = imgDataBefore.height;
    const wdth = imgDataBefore.width;

    var imgDataOutput = new ImageData(wdth, hght);

    var numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(imgDataBefore.data, imgDataAfter.data, 
                        imgDataOutput, wdth, hght, {threshold: 0.1});

     // this line does not work
     writeResultToPage(imgDataOutput)

}
```

#### What does not work

1. using the values from `imgDataOutput` to show the differences of the two images in a third image or on a canvas
2. What is not working: either a black image is created or the output-canvas is empty

This is the code that does not produce the desired result

```
function writeResultToPage(imgDataOutput)
{
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //  new HTMLCanvasElement();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.putImageData(imgDataOutput, 0, 0);
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
}
```

**Question**

Why is the output-canvas from  `writeResultToPage(imgDataOutput)` empty? 
What do i have to change to put `imgDataOutput` on the page as either an `<img>` or as a `<canvas>`?

Here is [my matching codepen](https://codepen.io/surfmuggle-the-styleful/pen/WBOaeO)

Comment: I have an updated example using a newer version of pixelmatch in [Compare two Images in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985143/6243352).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to add ".data" to imgDataOutput here:

```
var numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(imgDataBefore.data, imgDataAfter.data, 
                    imgDataOutput.data, wdth, hght, {threshold: 0.1});
```

I also added:

```
canvas.width = imgDataOutput.width;
canvas.height = imgDataOutput.height;
```

to writeResultToPage so that the canvas is the right size for the image.

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEVNmv